# How to automatically update/synchronize HTML code from one page to another in Dreamweaver CS5?

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I am building a basic website in Dreamweaver CS5 where many of the pages share a lot of the HTML code from one main page. As I am having to update this main page frequently I am wondering if there is a way to have the relevant shared code in the other pages update/sync automatically each time I make a change to the code in the main page? At the moment I am having to copy and paste the chunks of code over to each page which is a little laborious to say the least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create templates in Dreamweaver. 
Goto file > new and choose page type as html template.

Html template is basically a html file. with some comment tags specially for dreamweaver. You can use any of your html file as html template. In html template you can define editable regions

once you define html template you need to apply it to other html pages. Open a normal html file and goto Modify > Template > apply template to page.

Form now onwards whatever you modify on template page it would reflect in other pages which use that template. The content in the editable regions will be kept as it is.

Comment: Thanks Vijay - seems to make sense - will give it a go.

Comment: You are welcome. But design your templates carefully and which areas needs to be editable and which need not be, in the beginning itself. That would help you in the long run. :)