# Dreamweaver: How do I edit common code in multiple pages

Tags: html, dreamweaver, common-code

I am editing a website that has common code in multiple .html (example below). I am used to working with include files in .asp pages, so **how do I import the website into Dreamweaver CS5.5 so the common code is recognised like an include file?** Thank you!

```
<!-- begin [Menu] -->
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="news.html">News</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="news.html">News List</a></li>
        <li><a href="news_details.html">News Detail</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="portfolio_3columns.html">Portfolio</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="portfolio_1column.html">One Column</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio_2columns.html">Two Columns</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio_3columns.html">Three Columns</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="column_layouts.html">Features</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="column_layouts.html">Columns Layouts</a></li>
        <li><a href="page_elements.html">Page Elements</a></li>
        <li><a href="pricing_tables.html">Pricing Tables</a></li>
        <li><a href="twitter_feed.html">Twitter Feed</a></li>
        <li><a href="buttons.html">Buttons</a></li>
        <li><a href="404.html">404 Page</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- end [Menu] -->
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. HTML files cannot be imported or included in each other at all. Are you thinking of Dreamweaver Templates or Server-side Includes?

Comment: The same question is asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471050/how-to-automatically-update-synchronize-html-code-from-one-page-to-another-in-dr?rq=1
but I don't understand the solution provided. The solution given is to create a new template within Dreamweaver (file > new and choose page type as HTML) then apply that template to other pages, but the instructions create a new page. I want to select code in an existing page to be replicated on other pages.

Comment: I think I'll just need to change all .html extensions to .asp and use include files for common code. This method is more familiar to me.

Comment: @Dai yes you can include html file in another `<!--#include virtual="anotherpage.html" -->`

Comment: http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/include.html

Comment: @Gustonez Those are Server-Side Includes and aren't static HTML files.